# Combine two ffmpeg commands to produce one audio output

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use `libopus` to augment my audio using this decoder.

I can use it like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libopus -b:a 5.5k -ar 8000 output_550.ogg
ffmpeg -i output_550.ogg -ar 8000 output_550_ogg.wav
```

But I can't convert directly to `wav` - I get errors like these:

```
[wav @ 0x7fa9ac808800] opus codec not supported in WAVE format
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Function not implemented
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

How could I combine these to to get wav with a single command?

Comment: Do you want the final output to have Opus codec? P.S. your 2nd command converts back to PCM.

Comment: No, I use it for audio augmentation to add some noise. And these two commands give me the result I require. I just want them to efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two ffmpeg instances, piping the output of the first to the second.

`ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libopus -b:a 5.5k -ar 8000 -f nut - | ffmpeg -f nut -i - output_550_ogg.wav`

Comment: That's closer to what I want, but it should be possible to do that with one ffmpeg istance.

Comment: If you want the audio to undergo processing by libopus and yet be output as PCM, it's not possible to do it in one instance.